# Error al actualizar a Swift 3

Tags: swift2, swift3

Que tal, tengo un problema, mi aplicación con Xcode 7.3.1 corría perfectamente, desde que actualice Xcode 8 mi aplicación se actualizó y se convirtió el código automáticamente, me salieron unos errores pero los pude arreglar, corro mi app pero cuando intento abrir un UITableView que trae datos de una base de datos MySQL se muere la aplicación.

Este es el código en el cual la linea:
`jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSMutableArray`

Es la que da error.

En consola me sale este error:

Data downloaded

Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x1035ffc08) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x1035ffcd0).

Adjunto el código completo de ese archivo

```
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocal: class {
func itemsDownloaded(_ items: NSArray)
}


class HomeModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {


weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocal!

var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()


let urlPath: String = "http://localhost/iosws/lista_docentes.php"

func downloadItems() {

    let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    var session: Foundation.URLSession!
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default


    session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url)

    task.resume()

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    self.data.append(data);

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else {
        print("Data downloaded")
        self.parseJSON()
    }

}



func parseJSON() {

    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSMutableArray


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }

    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0..<jsonResult.count
    {

        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()



        if let iddocente = jsonElement["iddocente"] as? String,
            let nombres = jsonElement["nombres"] as? String
        {

            location.iddocente = iddocente
            location.nombres = nombres


        }

        locations.add(location)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations)

    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error que te está dando es que estás intentando asignar el resultado a un NSMutableArray y ahora devuelve un diccionario.

**Prueba asi:**

```
func parseJSON() {

    do{
        var jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }
}
```